# fancybox not closing - only close button disapear

Tags: jquery

Using jquery.fancybox-1.3.4,

I'm facing the following race condition -

Every now and then, when I click the fancybox close button `<a id="fancybox-close" style="display: block;"></a>` only the close button disappear and there is no way to close the rest of the fancy box.

code:

```
<a href="/exproduct.php?content_only=1&amp;id=970703&amp;TB_iframe=true" class="pframe">
        <img src="/994267-small/CHANGEME-addImageToP.jpg" alt="Kindle E-reader, 6 Glare-Free Touchscreen Display, Wi-Fi - Includes Special Offers">
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">$('a.pframe').fancybox();</script>
```

In the console I see:

> jquery.easing.1.3.js:20 Uncaught TypeError:
>   jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines in line #932

```
    $("#fancybox-overlay").hide()
    $("#fancybox-wrap").hide()
```

This is a brute force solution with out understanding the reason of the problem - but it works